# Ĉu estas ĝuste diri «ĝis» por signifi «iam antaŭ»?

Tags: prepositions

Mi ofte aŭdas «ĝis» por signifi ke io okazos antaŭ iu specifa dato. Ekzemple, imagu la jenan situacion:

> **Ĉefo:** Ĉu vi finis la raporton?
>
> **Dungito:** Ne, sed mi donos ĝin al vi ĝis vendredo.

En tiu okazo «ĝis vendredo» signifas «iam antaŭ vendredo». Sed por mi tio devus signifi ke la dungito tuj komencos malrapide etendi la brakojn por doni la raporton kaj tiu donado daŭros kelkajn tagojn, kaj finos vendrede.

Ĉu tia uzo estas normala aŭ ĉu oni povus diri ke ĝi estas erara?

Answer (score 9):

Mi opinias, ke tiu uzo estas ĝusta, kaj mi kredas, ke ĉi tiu ekzemplo zamenhofa, kiun mi trovis en [PMEG](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/rolmontriloj/rolvortetoj/direktaj_rolvortetoj/ghis.html#i-a4o), pruvas tion:

> *Ĉiu, kiu deziras partopreni en la konkurso, devas sendi ne pli malfrue ol **ĝis la 1-a Decembro 1895** […] raporton.* <sup>OV.200</sup> Ĉi tie Zamenhof esprimis dufoje la saman sencon. Oni povus aŭ forigi *ne pli malfrue ol*, aŭ anstataŭigi *ĝis* per N-finaĵo.

Estas aliaj ekzemploj en PMEG, en kiuj oni uzas *ĝis* por esprimi daŭron, sed en la ĉi-supra kaj ankaŭ aliaj en la sama paĝo, oni uzas *ĝis* por „montrado de lasta tempo por fini taskon“. Mi elektis ĉi tiun, ĉar ĝi ŝajnis al mi plej simila al la ekzemplo en via demando.

Se oni forigus *ne pli malfrue ol*, kiel la priskribo proponas, tio fariĝus:

> *Ĉiu, kiu deziras partopreni en la konkurso, devas sendi **ĝis la 1-a Decembro 1895** […] raporton.*

Kiu estas eĉ pli simila al via ekzemplo. Kompreneble, la sendado ne daŭrus la tutan tempon de la momento de la dirado ĝis la specifita dato.

Answer (score 7):

Lyubomir jam respondis kun atesto Zamenhofa, ke tiu lingvouzo estas bona. Mi volas ĉi tie nur aldoni pravigon lingvan:

La prepozicio *ĝis* esprimas la inkluzivatan finpunkton de ado (komparu kun *mi donos ĝin antaŭ vendredo*: vendrede estus jam tro malfrue, aŭ *mi donos ĝin dum vendredo*: ĵaŭde estus tro frue), sed ĝi nenion diras la kvalito de la ado.

Teorie do ankaŭ via spontanea interpreto estus pensebla, tiam temus pri daŭra ado: ~*mi estos donanta ĝin ĝis vendredo* (angle "will be giving", pole "będę dawać"). Sed la kutima interpreto de tia esprimo estas ado kiel punkta okazaĵo (angle "will give", pole "dam").

Answer (score 0):

Se temas pri pozitiva aserto, la signifo de *ĝis* estas *ne post*. Ekz. *Vi rajtas aliĝi ĝis la 1a de decembro*. Se temas pri negativa aserto, la signifo estas *ne antaŭ*, ekz. *Vi ne rajtas aliĝi ĝis la 1a de decembro*.

Comment: Tiu ekzemplo ŝajnas neproblema al mi, ĉar tiu «rajtado» ja daŭras la tutan tempon ekde nun ĝis la fina punkto. Kio konfuzas min estas kiam la vorto temas pri punkta ago, kiu momente kaj ekokazos kaj finos iam antaŭ la fina punkto, kiel la donado de la raporto.

Comment: Mi komprenas la konfuzon, precipe ĉar en mia denaska lingvo, la angla, oni ne uzas "until" tiamaniere se temas pri punkta ago. Tamen, en Esperanto ne estas baro kontraŭ tia uzo. La logiko estas identa kaj daŭre kaj punkte. Pozitive, _ĝis_ signifas _ne post_; negative ĝi signifas _ne antaŭ_.